# Screen shortcuts in terminal conflict with Konsole and general GUI settings

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, kde, konsole, gnu-screen

I'm starting to use Screen in my terminal use (tired of sshing many times when I need to work) anyway, I'm finding that the Screen shortcuts conflict with some of my general gui shortcuts.  The real problem child is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to tile.  If Kopete's running in the background, it does something with that and then if Kopete isn't active, Konsole tells me:

> Output has been suspended by presing Ctrl+S.  Prerss Ctrl+Q to resume.

I assume I could just roll up my selves and spend a day really mapping out my hotkeys but I was wondering if there was a quick workaround for this in terminal (maybe escaping all hot-heys when inside the terminal or some such thing?)

Also, if you have any other setup tips, feel free to post them as well.

Answer (score 1):

konsole -> edit profile  -> advance -> disable flow control using ctrl +s ctrl +q

Comment: Wow thanks, I never did find a solution to this.  I unchecked the option as you advised, however now when I do the key combination it gives me: `(i-search)`.  Thoughts?  Thanks again!

Comment: where is my up vote ? :)

Comment: @neanderslob If you find a good answer, upvote it or accept it if that answers your query.

Comment: @Anwar while I appreciated the attempt, I was not able to get the desired result using the suggested key binding.  I certainly would upvote and accept if it had worked for my problem.